# Using adjective before the word "something/someone"

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

We normally use these kinds of sentences:

> I need something strong or I have to hire someone intelligent.

Here, the words "strong" and "intelligent" modify the nouns something and someone.So,we can call them adjective.My question is can we use those adjectives before something/someone like below:

> I need strong something  or I have to hire intelligent someone.

if i unable to do that what are the grammatical rules behind these.Please clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, but with one qualification. You need to use an article:

> I need ***a*** strong something.
>   I have to hire ***an*** intelligent someone.

By putting the adjective in front of the pronoun, you end up turning the two words into a noun phrase, and rules for articles in front of nouns take effect. Mass nouns often don't require articles, but neither *something* nor *someone* can be considered to be part of a mass noun phrase.

---

Note that *an intelligent someone*, while not ungrammatical, is less idiomatic than *an intelligent person*.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.